# What is the meaning of -m in Python command?

Tags: python

Taking this command to start local server for example, the command includes -m, what is the meaning of -m in genearl?

```
python3 -m http.server
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, which can be invoked using `python3 --help`.

```
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

Instead of importing the module in another script (like `import <module-name>`), you directly run it as a script.

Answer (score -1):

The -m stands for module-name in Python.